# Play audio data from java ByteArray

Tags: java, android, streaming, audio-streaming, pcm

I have a 16-bit PCM audio data from an android app and I want to stream and play it on a webpage from the format as seen on this screenshot.

Is there a way to directly play audio buffers on webpage without having a server to serve an audio file? I'm open to suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a Data Uri to map the data to a file on-the-fly and input that into something that can play an auio file from a uri (such as the HTML audio component).
You could also just save this buffer to a file and play that.

Comment: Thank you but I prefer a more detailed explanation